# Receive XML content from Server Side : Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following script for my client side where i fills up the form and send to server for processing :

```
           function AjaxCall(){
           var xmlval='<person><name>'+personObject.GetPersonName()+'</name> <contact>'+personObject.GetPersonContact()+'</contact><about>'+personObject.GetPersonName()+'</about></person>';
                //var datas='?xmlvalue='+xmlval;
                xmlhttp.open("POST",'ajaxExecutePersonData.php'+xmlval,true);

                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

                xmlhttp.send(xmlval);
              }
```

I need to know how can i receive this POST to the ajaxExecutePersonData.php

and get response.

I am sending xml Object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont think you are reeving something at your PHP end, because you are not sending it as querystring.

Comment: @Arfeen: yep and he's even doing it on the GET side. not POST :) for GET use 'ajaxExecutePersonData.php?xmlval=' + xmlval (but you need to make sure it's urlencoded)

Comment: i want to send xml object.Can you give idea how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the xml as param like this

```
var params = "foo=bar&bar=foo";
```

in your case

```
var params = "xmlval=" + xmlval;
```

and then set the appropriate headers like

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

and replace the send() call with this one:

```
xmlhttp.send(params)
```

and then you have $_POST["xmlval"] in your php script.

hope this helps :)

Comment: actually i want to send an xml script as an xml Object...Did you explain with that aspect?

Comment: well, your terminology is odd :) xml cannot be a script, because a script is something that is runnable. you have to interprete the xml on the PHP side for example with `simplexml_load_string($_POST["xmlval"]` - so yes, i had that in mind.

Comment: in that case am i sending a query string?Or an xml object?